# Minecraft: FPS drops on second monitor?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, minecraft, fps

On my main Monitor the FPS are at about 60. If i connect my 2nd monitor and want to play on the monitor the FPS directly drops to about 20 - 30 FPS. Is there something i can do about it or is there something im doing wrong?

Im using Badlion Client to play Minecraft.

Comment: Are you using the monitors simultaneously or one at a time?

Comment: Im using the second monitor to play minecraft and the first one doesnt have any other programms opened.

Comment: What is your graphics card?

Comment: Your external monitor is using integrated graphics while your normal monitor is using the dedicated graphics card. That could be one reason.

Comment: Some information would help about your computer, graphical card and its ports, and the connectors.

Comment: @zomega  Intel UHD 730 Graphics Card

Comment: @JonasReimers What is the configured refresh rate? On Windows this is under "advanced display settings".

Comment: While this Intel KB doc does not directly talk about your card, the advice might be useful: [Graphics Frame Rate is Being Limited by Main Monitor](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000056871/graphics.html)

Comment: Are they the same resolution? If not, you'd expect the higher res to take more resources to drive.